# Android: Reading the string to specific character

Tags: java, android, regex, split, substring

I am reading commands from `micro controller` in this format `@transfer:Off#` but some times the `micro controller` sends garbage commands like `@transfer:Off#@waste#` as the `controller's programming` is done by some other unknown `programmer`. I only need `@transfer:Off#` string which starts from `@` and ends with first `#`
The compiler should wait for `@` at the start and read the `string` until first `#` comes and stop reading on wards.

I am getting the normal commands by using following chunk of `code`.

```
if(values.length > -1){
    command = values[0].substring(1, values[0].length() - 1);
    int commandLength = command.split(":").length;
    if(commandLength>1){
        identifier = command.split(":")[0];
        value = command.split(":")[1];
    }else{
        value = "No";
    }
 }
```

How I get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't know the length of the `string` that the `micro controller` is sending you, you will need to `split` the `string` by `#` and getting the first member of the `array`.

```
String recieveString = "@transfer:Off#@waste#";
String resStr = recieveString.split("#")[0];
```